# Any derivation map is a linear combination of directional derivatives

Tags: calculus, geometry, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry

> Fix a point $\mathbf p\in \mathbb R^n$. Given $\mathbf v\in \mathbb R^n$, define the directional derivative $\nabla_{\mathbf v}$ of a function $f$ at the point $\mathbf p$ as
> $$\nabla_{\mathbf v}f(\mathbf p)=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(\mathbf p+t\mathbf v)-f(\mathbf p)}t$$
> Note that this is a map $\nabla_{\mathbf v}:C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)\to C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ where $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ is the set of all real valued smooth functions on $\mathbb R^n$.
>
> Now, let us have a map $D:C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)\to C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ that satisfies the following properties-
>
> 1. $D(f+g)(\mathbf p)=D(f)(\mathbf p)+D(g)(\mathbf p)$
> 2. $D(cf)(\mathbf p)=cD(f)(\mathbf p)$
> 3. $D(fg)(\mathbf p)=fD(g)(\mathbf p)+gD(f)(\mathbf p)$
>
> Such a map is called a *derivation* at $\mathbf p$. Prove that any such derivation maps can be written as a linear combination of $\{\nabla_{\mathbf e_i}\}_{i=1}^n$.

I have proved that the directional derivative map $\nabla_{\mathbf v}$ satisfies properties (1),(2) and (3). Using that, we can also very easily show that any linear combination of $\{\nabla_{\mathbf e_i}\}_{i=1}^n$ also satisfies properties (1),(2) and (3). As a part of a previous exercise (which may be of use in this part), I have proved
$$\nabla_{\mathbf {v}+\mathbf{w}}=\nabla_{\mathbf v}\\\nabla_{c\mathbf v}=c\nabla_{\mathbf v}$$
But, I have no idea how to show that any derivation is a linear combination of directional derivatives.

Comment: Suppose $v=v_1e_1+v_2e_2+\dots +v_ne_n$, then as you have shown $\nabla_v=v_1\nabla_{e_1}+v_2\nabla_{e_2}+\dots + v_n \nabla_{e_n}$. How can you get the coordinates $v_i$ using only $\nabla_v$, and the coordinate functions $x_i$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f\in C^\infty(\mathbf R^n)$, $p \in \mathbf R^n$, $D$ a derivation at $p$. By Taylor, we can write
$$ f(x) = f(p) + \sum_{i = 1}^n h_i(x) (x_i - p_i) $$
with $h_i \in C^\infty(\mathbf R^n)$ such that $h_i(p) = \nabla_{e_i}f(p)$. Applying $D$, we have, writing $\pi_i\colon \mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R$, $x \mapsto x_i$ for the projections:
\begin{align*}
  Df &= D(f(p)) + \sum_{i = 1}^n D\bigl(h_i(\pi_i - p_i)\bigr)\\
     &= \sum_{i = 1}^n \bigl(h_i(p) D(\pi_i) + Dh_i (\pi_i - p_i)(p)\bigr)\\
     &= \sum_{i = 1}^n D(\pi_i) \cdot \nabla_{e_i}f(p) 
\end{align*}
Hence,
$$ D = \sum_{i = 1}^n D(\pi_i) \nabla_{e_i} f(p) $$